# separate (or similar function) with multiple or no occurrences of splitting character

Tags: r, regex

I have a tibble like this

```
library("tidyverse")
tib <- tibble(x = c("lemon", "yellow, banana", "red, big, apple"))
```

I would like to create two new columns named `description` and `fruit` and extract the *last word after the comma* using `separate` (if there is a comma; otherwise, I would like to just copy the word in the cell).

So far, I have

```
tib %>%
    separate(x, ", ", into = c("description", "fruit"), remove = FALSE)
```

but this doesn't quite do what I want, yielding:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x               description fruit 
  <chr>           <chr>       <chr> 
1 lemon           lemon       NA    
2 yellow, banana  yellow      banana
3 red, big, apple red         big   
Warning messages:
1: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 1 rows [3]. 
2: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [1].
```

The output I want is:

```
  x               description fruit 
1 lemon           NA          lemon    
2 yellow, banana  yellow      banana
3 red, big, apple red, big    apple
```

Can someone point me to the part I'm missing?

***EDIT***

The goal doesn't have to be achieved using `separate`. `mutate` would also work, and solutions are equally appreciated!

Comment: Does it have to be using separate? Might be easier to use mutate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be better with `extract`.  Here, we can use capture groups to capture the characters as a group.  It is better to start at the end (`$`) and go backwards, i.e. word (`\\w+`) at the end captured, succeeds a `,` or space (`\\s`) and all other characters in the first capture group (`(.*?)`)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tib %>%
   extract(x, into = c("description", "fruit"), remove = FALSE, '(.*?),?\\s?(\\w+$)')
```

Or using regex lookaround with `separate`, by specifying the delimiter as either the `,` followed by space or the start (`^`) of the string followed by a word (`\\w+`) at the end (`$`) of the string

```
tib %>%
   separate(x, into = c("description", 'fruit'),
       remove = FALSE, '(, |^)(?=\\w+$)') %>%
   mutate(description = na_if(description, ""))
```

---

Also, another option with `separate` would be to insert a new delimiter before the last word and then use that as `sep`

```
library(stringr)
tib %>% 
  mutate(x1 = str_replace(x, ',? ?(\\w+)$', ";\\1")) %>% 
  separate(x1, into = c("description", "fruit"), sep=";") %>%
  mutate(description = na_if(description, ""))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  x               description fruit 
#  <chr>           <chr>       <chr> 
#1 lemon           <NA>        lemon 
#2 yellow, banana  yellow      banana
#3 red, big, apple red, big    apple
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to grab description - replace last comma and everything after it. `",[^,]+$"` matches comma followed by anything that is not a comma up to the end.

For getting the fruit, use the `word` function of `stringr` package to grab the last word.

```
tib %>%
    mutate(desc = if_else(grepl(",", x), sub(",[^,]+$", "", x), NA_character_),
           fruit = stringr::word(x, -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex-based solutions, like the other two here, are probably better. But if for whatever reason you'd like to work with lists of words instead, here's another option.

Split the text into a list of strings. The description is everything but the item at position `length(words)`. The fruit is the last item. If having a blank string instead of `NA` is fine, you can delete the `na_if` bit.

```r
library(dplyr)

tib <- tibble(x = c("lemon", "yellow, banana", "red, big, apple"))
tib %>%
  mutate(words = strsplit(x, ", "),
         description = purrr::map_chr(words, ~paste(.[-length(.)], collapse = ", ")) %>% na_if(""),
         fruit = purrr::map_chr(words, last))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   x               words     description fruit 
#>   <chr>           <list>    <chr>       <chr> 
#> 1 lemon           <chr [1]> <NA>        lemon 
#> 2 yellow, banana  <chr [2]> yellow      banana
#> 3 red, big, apple <chr [3]> red, big    apple
```

Obviously you can then drop the `words` column—I left it in just to show its type.